# Deleting Entire Row in Excel VBA From A Certain Cell Down

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete whole rows of data if a date is more than a week later than today, but I don't want to delete the header. Today's date is a variable appearing in A2.

Edit: Column A has dates in the format of dd/mm/yyyy.

This code is what I have at the moment but it doesn't work and erases the header:

```
Sub deletedates()

Dim firstDate As Date, secondDate As Date
Dim i As Range

firstDate = DateValue(Range("A2"))
secondDate = DateAdd("d", 6, firstDate)

MsgBox secondDate

For Each i In Range("A:A")
If i.Value > secondDate Then
i.Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete

End If
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: How many cells do you have? Instead of using `Range("A:A") - can you not use specific range in which the data is input? Also, the loop doesn't work as expected because you are deleting the cells while traversing it.

Answer (score 1):

I've added something that helps two issues:

1) The lngCounter = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).row finds the last row of data, as your original code will look at each cell in Column A, which could be over a million if you use newer versions of Excel.

2) I have started the search for data at row 2 of column A to avoid deleting the header row.

Hope this helps!

```
Sub deletedates()

Dim firstDate As Date, secondDate As Date
Dim i As range
Dim lngCounter As Long
Dim strRange As String

lngCounter = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).row 'Find last row of data

strRange = "a2:a" & lngCounter 'Start at Row 2, Column A, finish at last row of Column A

firstDate = DateValue(range("A2"))
secondDate = DateAdd("d", 6, firstDate)

'MsgBox secondDate

    For Each i In range(strRange) 'Starts at second row of data.

        If i.Value > secondDate Then
        i.Select
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: THanks SKip Intro, the loop seems to work now as the header isn't deleted now- however it doesn't seem to delete the rows which I need to get rid off? Possibly a problem with my activecell.entirerow.delete command?

Comment: I was using dummy dates data in my test and it seemed to delete the required rows. Could you amend your question to show what your data in column A looks like so I can do a like for like test?

Comment: It seems I have to run the code several times before I'm finally left with data from the dates I need. Not sure why this is the case...